# Exit of App in Cordova can not clear sessions on server

Tags: php, cordova, session, phonegap

I use Cordova to build an online application, i use some session variables on my server(php). when i exit of this app, the sessions still exists on my server. how can i fix it to unset all of sessions automatically?
here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "helloworld",
  "displayName": "HelloCordova",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Apache Cordova Team",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "cordova-android": "^7.1.4",
    "cordova-browser": "^5.0.4",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-dialogs": "^2.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^3.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-nativestorage": "^2.3.2",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "^2.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-share": "^0.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-x-toast": "^2.7.2"
  },
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-dialogs": {},
      "cordova-plugin-nativestorage": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-x-toast": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
      "cordova-plugin-network-information": {},
      "nl.madebymark.share": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "browser",
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the native `onDestroy` and `applicationWillTerminate` functions for Android and iOS, respectively. Try searching for plugins by adding those keywords. It seems some cordova plugins exist for these events:

- https://github.com/agamemnus/cordova-plugin-ondestroy
- https://github.com/bsorrentino/cordova-broadcaster

However, I haven't checked the validity of them. There's a good chance the application may actually be already destroyed by the time the event is received by your `WebView` application over the cordova bridge.

On another note, why not just persist the session token in your app as well? Just store it somewhere securely. The fact that the user doesn't have to log in each time the app is closed is a great feature, not a bug.

Comment: thank you for answering, but i have to use some sessions on the server, i think when server holds all sessions, its memory may be full! i just need clear all of server sessions automatically when leaving the app.